# Redirect all existent and non-existent pages and folders within subfolder to one page when custom DocumentRoot set

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, document-root

I have the next file structure:

```
.htaccess
index.php
public/
├─ v1/
│  ├─ .htaccess
│  ├─ index.php
├─ index.php
```

I've set document root on server level to `public` subfolder in order to remove it from url.

I need all the requests containing `v1` in url to be redirected to `v1/index.php`.

**My root `.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**and `v1/.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Expected behavior:**

Non-existing `https://example.com/v1/test` page should redirect to `https://example.com/v1/`.

**What I get instead:**

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in second `.htaccess`. I also suspect that custom **Document Root** can be a problem too here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try having your root .htaccess in following manner once and give it a shot and remove your inner .htaccess(keep backup of it in your local system though but don't have it on system). Clear your brorwser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/public(?:/\S*)*\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/v1(?:/\S*)*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/v1(?:/\S*)*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/v1/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(v1)/.+/?$ /$1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^v1/?$  public/v1/index.php [QSA,L]
```

NOTE: Will add detailed explanation in morning time as its too late night for me.

Comment: I've tried the code (fixed the typo in folder name in root htaccess), but still getting the same error when open non-existent page within `v1` subfolder, and no redirect when open existing one.

Comment: @Acidon, Ok, I have made a small change now, could you please do check my latest code(2nd htaccess file) and try it out once, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sadly, the result is still the same.

Comment: @Acidon, Is it redirecting url? when you hit that http://localhost:80/v1/test1?

Comment: @Acidon, I have made 1 more edit to my 2nd htaccess could you please do check it once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @RivinderSingh13, still same, when I go to `https://example.com/v1/test1` it will give Not Found error if the page test1.php does not exist in the folder, or it will just open the page if it exists.

Comment: @Acidon, oh ok, I have added one more condition in root .htacces now, kindly update both files and let me know how it goes. Make sure to clear browser cache before testing your urls.

Comment: Still same, and now `v1/index.php` shows Not Found error too.

Comment: @Acidon, I had removed one line from v1 htaccess, kindly try it once and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Same as the last time - no redirect, also `https://example.com/v1/index.php` works but `https://example.com/v1/` doesn't.

Comment: @Acidon, Sorry for same, I am trying my best to help here. I have made edit in my rules now, could you please do check with new rules once and let me know how it goes? Make sure to place newly posted rules and clear cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: It redirects, but to the url containing `public` subfolder in url. `public` has to be hidden all the time.

Comment: @Acidon, ok sure, applied 1 more patch to code, could you please do test with newly edited code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Still `https://example.com/v1/test1` redirects to `https://example.com/public/v1/`... I really appreciate you helping me with this one.

Comment: @Acidon, not an issue, trying best to help here. I have changed rules now, kindly try with new rules and check, make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: same as last time and now `https://example.com/v1/` redirects to `https://example.com/public/v1/` too.

Comment: actually it shows 404 for `https://example.com/v1/` (forgot to fix your typo in v1 folder name)

Comment: @Acidon, is it redirecting now without public folder name in it?

Comment: nope, still `https://example.com/v1/test1` redirects to `https://example.com/public/v1/` (and `https://example.com/v1/` returns 404).

Comment: @Acidon, I have made slight changes in rules now, could you please try now, used different APACHE default variable, if this doesn't work then we will go step by step.

Comment: now I get 'Internal Server Error' on both `https://example.com/v1/test1` and `https://example.com/v1/` requests.

Comment: @Acidon, fixed the typo now, kindly do check updated ones.

Comment: Now `https://example.com/v1/test1` redirects to `https://example.com/v1` (notice trailing slash missing) and gives 404, and `https://example.com/v1/` gives 404 as well.

Comment: @Acidon, Ok taken care of `/` try edited ones now and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Redirect from `https://example.com/v1/test1` to `https://example.com/v1/` works now, but `https://example.com/v1/` still returns 404.

Comment: @Acidon, ok do 1 thing your inner v1 .htaccess make it NULL OR remove it for time being and try only root htaccess with edited rules and let me know how it goes. I hope this should work, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've removed `.htaccess` from `v1` folder, but still getting the 404s. Redirect works as expected.

Comment: @Acidon, Ok, change only last line **to** `RewriteRule ^v1/?$  /v1/index.php [QSA,L]` once and let me know how it goes, make sure to clear your browser cache and then test your URLs please.

Comment: Now everything gives 404 and redirect is not working.

Comment: @Acidon, ohhh :( but v1 folder has index.php present inside it right? And its htaccess is not there, can you please confirm these 2 points once?

Comment: Everything is correct. I also notice that I get 404 on any existing page inside the `v1` and no redirect.

Comment: @Acidon, ok lets try another way, I have changed my rules again, kindly do check them once and let me know.

Comment: @Acidon, ohhh and also change your %DOCUMENT_ROOT to root(level before public) then it should work I believe, kindly try it out once.

Comment: Redirect loop on direct 'https://example.com/v1/' request, and on `https://example.com/v1/test1` request it redirects correctly but then goes into redirect loop too.

Comment: @Acidon, yeah it means we are on right path. could you please try my updated rules once?

Comment: I've also changed DocumentRoot on server to remove the `/public` part and restarted the apache. Still getting the same redirect loops as in previous comment.

Comment: @Acidon, request you to kindly try my edited rules as mentioned in previous comments and let me know if this helps.

Comment: I've applied your latest fix and redirect from `https://example.com/v1/test1` to `https://example.com/v1/` works correctly, but `https://example.com/v1/` still returns 404.

Comment: @Acidon, considering that your %DOCUMENT_ROOT is path of root eg: `/root/hddocs` etc path just before 1 level of public and htaccess. And then change   last line of current rules to `RewriteRule ^v1/?$ /v1/index.php [QSA,L]` and see how it goes?

Comment: Yes, %DOCUMENT_ROOT path is correct. I've changed last line, but still 404, redirect is working.

Comment: @Acidon, ohhh I got it, I am sleep its 3 AM here. Try my edited rules once and Congrats me and us if we are Good here :) let me know quickly

Comment: @Acidon, Your welcome, I am very very very happy that I could help you, hard work paid off, cheers and keep asking Good questions on this great site, cheers, take care. Its 3 AM IST but I am Loving it :)